# ForEach "implicitly-synthesized declarations" error when passing array of videos in Swift Tik Tok clone :(

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, avkit

These errors

"Cannot declare entity named '$reel'; the '$' prefix is reserved for implicitly-synthesized declarations"

"Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'Binding<[Reel]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"

Both errors are on this ForEach

```
ForEach($reels) { $reel in

          ReelsPlayer(reel: $reel)
}
```

Is this because my videos are a custom type, and therefore swift is not able to ID them which is giving me the 'RandomAccessCollection' error?

I have a TabView {} and am trying to make each page a new video similar to tik tok or vine. It works when I pass in dummy data but when I pass from my array of videos I get those errors.

The View:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ReelsView: View {
   
  @State var currentReel = ""
     
  // extracting AVPlayer from media file
  @State var reels: [Reel] = MediaFileJSON.map { item -> Reel in
     
    let url = Bundle.main.path(forResource: item.url, ofType: "MP4") ?? ""
     
    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: url))
     
    return Reel(player: player, mediaFile: item)
  }
   
  var body: some View {
     
    // setting width and height for rotated view
    GeometryReader { proxy in
       
      let size = proxy.size
       
      // vertical page tab view
      TabView(selection: $currentReel) {
         
        ForEach($reels) { $reel in // **ERRORS HERE**

          ReelsPlayer(reel: $reel)
          // setting width
          .frame(width: size.width)
          .padding()
          // rotate content
          .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
        }
      }
      // Rotate View
      .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: 90))
      // setting height as width
      .frame(width: size.height)
      .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
      // setting max width
      .frame(width: size.width)
       
    }
  }
}

struct ReelsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
  }
}

struct ReelsPlayer: View, Identifiable {
  var id: ObjectIdentifier
   
   
  @Binding var reel: Reel
   
  var body: some View {
     
    ZStack {
       
       
    }
  }
}
```

MediaFile struct:

```
struct MediaFile: Identifiable {
  var id = UUID().uuidString
  var url: String
  var title: String
  var isExpanded: Bool = false
}

var MediaFileJSON = [
   
  MediaFile(url: "Reel1", title: "Apple AirTag......."),
  MediaFile(url: "Reel2", title: "this is the second."),
  MediaFile(url: "Reel3", title: "the third"),
  MediaFile(url: "Reel4", title: "wooooooooooooo ya"),
  MediaFile(url: "Reel5", title: "ay ayayayayay ayay lsdfk sl"),
  MediaFile(url: "Reel6", title: "this is the last one....."),
   
]
```

Reel struct:

```
struct Reel: Identifiable {
   
  var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  var player: AVPlayer?
  var mediaFile: MediaFile
}
```

Comment: Start by removing the `$` in `ForEach($reels)`

Comment: @jnpdx tried that and it gives me "Cannot convert value of type 'Reel' to expected argument type 'Binding<Reel>'" on the line below it

Comment: Leave it on the second one, but remove it from the first `ForEach(reels) { $reel in` (this is assuming you're on iOS 15)

Comment: @jnpdx yea thats what I tried the first time... but Im on IOS 14.5, so maybe thats the problem? ill try to download the xcode 13 beta to see if 15 works

Comment: Yeah, if you are on 14, you need to create a custom binding. Lots of posts here about it or I can write up an answer if you want.

Comment: @jnpdx gotcha, Ill try it on 15 and see if it works first, thanks for the help :)